# How do I get the default value for a grails domain class property

Tags: grails, grails-orm, default-value

Given a domain that starts

```
class MyDomain {

    /* pre injuries board */
    Boolean isSomething = false
```

Is there a way I can get the default value without instantiating an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not without doing something like this:

```
class MyDomain {
    public static final Boolean IS_SOMETHING_DEFAULT = false
    Boolean isSomething = IS_SOMETHING_DEFAULT

     ...
}
```

Later...

```
Boolean myDomainDefault = MyDomain.IS_SOMETHING_DEFAULT
```

Comment: although it does seems a bit odd

Comment: Thanks Ted, it does seem odd, but it's a good workaround, does exactly what I need